# Elasticsearch partial update script: Clear array and replace with new values

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents like:

```
{
  MyProp: ["lorem", "ipsum", "dolor"]
  ... lots of stuff here ...
}
```

My documents can be quite big (but these `MyProp` fields are not), and expensive to generate from scratch.

Sometimes I need to update batches of these - it would therefore be beneficial to do a *partial* update (to save "indexing client" processing power and bandwidth, and thus time) and replace the MyProp values with new values.

Example of original document:

```
{
  MyProp: ["lorem", "ipsum", "dolor"]
  ... lots of stuff here ...
}
```

Example of updated document (or rather how it should look):

```
{
  MyProp: ["dolor", "sit"]
  ... lots of stuff here ...
}
```

From what I have seen, this includes scripting.

Can anyone enlighten me with the remaining bits of the puzzle?

### Bounty added:

I'd like to also have some instructions of how to make these in a batch statement, if possible.

Comment: Can you show one update you'd like to make?

Comment: @Val, done! Thanks

Comment: Are you willing to update `MyProp` in a single document at a time or in several documents?

Comment: Most of the time, they need unique values.

Comment: What Elasticsearch version?

Comment: @AndreiStefan ES5 is OK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [update by query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html) in order to do batch updates. This works since ES 2.3 onwards, otherwise you need to [install a plugin](https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-action-updatebyquery).

```
POST index/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.myProp += newProp",
    "params": {
      "newProp": "sit"
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

You can of course use whatever query you want in order to select the documents on which `MyProp` needs to be updated. For instance, you could have a query to select documents having some specific `MyProp` values to be replaced.

The above will only add a new value to the existing array. If you need to completely replace the `MyProp` array, then you can also change the script to this:

```
POST index/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.myProp = newProps",
    "params": {
      "newProps": ["dolor", "sit"]
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

Note that you also need to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-security.html#enable-dynamic-scripting) in order for this to work.

**UPDATE**

If you simply want to update a single document you can use the [partial document update API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#_updates_with_a_partial_document), like this:

```
POST test/type1/1/_update
{
    "doc" : {
        "MyProp" : ["dolor", "sit"]
    }
}
```

This will effectively replace the `MyProp` array in the specified document.

If you want to go the bulk route, you don't need scripting to achieve what you want:

```
POST index/type/_bulk
{ "update" : {"_id" : "1"} }
{ "doc" : {"MyProp" : ["dolor", "sit"] } }
{ "update" : {"_id" : "2"} }
{ "doc" : {"MyProp" : ["dolor", "sit"] } }
```

Comment: Will this effectively clear the existing values though?

Comment: Sorry to bother you. Can you also give an example on how to do this in non-batch mode? (for clarity)

Comment: Sorry again. For the single document partial update. Are you positive this would replace the array and clear existing values?

Comment: Yes that will completely replace the array and clear the previous values.

Comment: So just issuing a bulk with partial api updates would do the thing? I'm not sure that your first example applies as I never push new values to existing values, only replacement. I understood the Docs as that they were adding new values without deleting the old ones.

Comment: yes, that's correct. I've also added a bulk call that doesn't use any scripting and allows you to send several partial updates at once (the same updates as in my `_update` call). Each of those updates will replace the `MyProp` array/values.

Comment: Thanks, let's wait 24hrs for the bounty.

Comment: Thank you, don't hesitate to ask if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

Would a `_bulk` update work for you?

```
POST test/type1/_bulk
{"update":{"_id":1}}
{"script":{"inline":"ctx._source.MyProp += new_param","params":{"new_param":"bla"},"lang":"groovy"}}
{"update":{"_id":2}}
{"script":{"inline":"ctx._source.MyProp += new_param","params":{"new_param":"bla"},"lang":"groovy"}}
{"update":{"_id":3}}
{"script":{"inline":"ctx._source.MyProp += new_param","params":{"new_param":"bla"},"lang":"groovy"}}
....
```

And you would also need to enable inline scripting for `groovy`. What the above would do is to add a `bla` value to the listed documents in `MyProp` field. Of course, depending on your requirements many other changes can be performed in that script.