# Is there bulk partial update in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have a model with 50 properties for elasticsearch and I am transferring datas to elastic search. However, I have aproximately 150000 documents in my elasticsearch alias and I want to update these documents' 3 properties with bulk partial update. I know that there is bulk update and partial update separately but ıs there partial bulk update in elasticsearch?

Comment: Just to be sure: Those 3 values are not scriptable based on either static values or the existing fields, so you will need to send the actual values for each document?

Comment: this answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40824645/elasticsearch-partial-update-script-clear-array-and-replace-with-new-values/40863669#40863669 (see the very last bulk command at the bottom of the answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send partial updates using the bulk API. Here's an example

```cs
private static void Main()
{
    var defaultIndex = "documents";
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));

    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
        .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex);

    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    if (client.IndexExists(defaultIndex).Exists)
        client.DeleteIndex(defaultIndex);

    var docs = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => new MyDocument(i) 
        {
            Message = $"message {i}"
        });

    // bulk index the documents   
    var bulkResponse = client.Bulk(b => b
        .IndexMany(docs)
        .Refresh(Refresh.WaitFor)
    );

    var searchResponse = client.Search<MyDocument>(s => s
        .Sort(so => so.Ascending("_id"))
    );

    // update the documents
    bulkResponse = client.Bulk(b => b
        .UpdateMany<MyDocument, object>(docs, (bu, doc) => 
        {
            if (doc.Id % 3 == 0)
            {
                // use script to update
                bu.Id(doc.Id).Script(s => s
                    .Source("ctx._source.message = 'message ' + (Integer.parseInt(ctx._id) * 2);")
                );
            }
            else if (doc.Id % 2 == 0)
            {
                // use partial document to update
                bu.Id(doc.Id).Doc(new { message = "updated message" });
            }
            else
            {
                // send the original document to update
                bu.Doc(doc);
            }

            return bu;
        })
        .Refresh(Refresh.WaitFor)
    );

    searchResponse = client.Search<MyDocument>(s => s
        .Sort(so => so.Ascending("_id"))
    );    
}


public class MyDocument 
{
    public MyDocument(int id) => Id = id;

    public int Id { get; set; }  

    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

The final search response returns

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 10,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "documents",
        "_type" : "mydocument",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 1,
          "message" : "message 1"
        },
        "sort" : [
          "1"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "documents",
        "_type" : "mydocument",
        "_id" : "10",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 10,
          "message" : "updated message"
        },
        "sort" : [
          "10"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "documents",
        "_type" : "mydocument",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 2,
          "message" : "updated message"
        },
        "sort" : [
          "2"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "documents",
        "_type" : "mydocument",
        "_id" : "3",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 3,
          "message" : "message 6"
        },
        "sort" : [
          "3"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "documents",
        "_type" : "mydocument",
        "_id" : "4",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 4,
          "message" : "updated message"
        },
        "sort" : [
          "4"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "documents",
        "_type" : "mydocument",
        "_id" : "5",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 5,
          "message" : "message 5"
        },
        "sort" : [
          "5"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "documents",
        "_type" : "mydocument",
        "_id" : "6",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 6,
          "message" : "message 12"
        },
        "sort" : [
          "6"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "documents",
        "_type" : "mydocument",
        "_id" : "7",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 7,
          "message" : "message 7"
        },
        "sort" : [
          "7"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "documents",
        "_type" : "mydocument",
        "_id" : "8",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 8,
          "message" : "updated message"
        },
        "sort" : [
          "8"
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "documents",
        "_type" : "mydocument",
        "_id" : "9",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : 9,
          "message" : "message 18"
        },
        "sort" : [
          "9"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Observe that the source documents have been updated

1. documents with an `_id` divisible by 3 have updated the document using a scripted update
2. docuemnts with an `_id` divisible by 2 have updated the document using a partial update.
3. Remaining documents have been updated by passing the original document; this results in a `noop` in the bulk response.

Comment: thanks a lot , it is very useful and solved my problem