# ACID update of ElasticSearch Document

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to build a Tinder-like system right now. Here I need to know which cards have already been seen.

If I save the cards in ElasticSearch, and then have such a document:

{ nama: David, location: {lat, lon}, seenFromUsers: [] }

I'm just wondering if it makes sense to create a list in the object itself. Probably there are 2000 entries in it. 
But if I do an update in ElasticSearch, then I always have to pass all 2000 entries. If two users do this at the same time, does one get lost? How can I simply add another ID to the array? Is that even possible?

What other solutions are there?

Comment: this answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40824645/elasticsearch-partial-update-script-clear-array-and-replace-with-new-values/40863669#40863669 (Hint: scripted update)

Comment: have in mind that elasticsearch is not acid compatible by design - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/concurrency-solutions.html

Answer (score 1):

One other solution would be a complete different approach. Instead if creating documents like this

```
{
  "name": "David",
  "location": { "lat": ..., "lon": ...},
  "seenFromUsers": ["Laura", "Simone"]
}
```

think in Relations like this:

```
{
  "name": "David",
  "seenBy": "Laura"
}

{
  "name": "David",
  "seenBy": "Simone"
}
```

this approach will give you simpler queries, and the ACID problem is solved. New profile views are simply new documents...

As a benefit, you´ll get rid of inner objects and it will be more easy to add additional data to this relation:

```
{
  "name": "David",
  "seenBy": "Laura",
  "timestamp": ...,
  "liked": true
}

{
  "name": "David",
  "seenBy": "Simone",
  "timestamp": ...,
  "liked": false
}
```

And now you´ll be able to do a simple query for all positive likes of a profile, or bi-directional likes/matches...

Comment: But how can connect this two Tables than in ElasticSearch? hasChild? Can you explain this more?

Comment: I think, the acid problem is solved in a elegant manner.  You should raise another question in order to discuss it without messing this question up with other aspects of your application and keep the title/question/answer intact. I'll find the new question. Please give us there as many details as possible. Cheers!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56430019/how-to-get-unseen-nearby-documents-from-a-amplify-appsync-elasticsearch-d